# formatar paragrafo <p>

Tags: javascript, html, text

Eu executo algumas funções js num determinado texto. adicionando classes e retirando as classes. O html final gera algumas quebras no paragrafo, assim:

```
<p style="text-align: left;">
“obviamente”
“ nem todos apoiam”
“ o brasil.”
</p>
```

Eu preciso tratar esse paragrafo para ficar assim:

```
<p style="text-align: left;">
“obviamente nem todos apoiam o brasil.”
</p>
```

Senão da próxima vez que eu usar a mesma função, ela não executa direito (pois uso regex).

Alguma ideia de como tratar esse paragrafo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essas quebras se tratam de [Text Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode). Veja o exemplo abaixo (inspecione o elemento do parágrafo):

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p')

const text1 = document.createTextNode('text1 ')
const text2 = document.createTextNode('text2 ')
const text3 = document.createTextNode('text3')

p.appendChild(text1)
p.appendChild(text2)
p.appendChild(text3)

console.log('ChildNodes:', p.childNodes.length)
```

```html
<p></p>
```

O que você pode fazer é utilizar o método [normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize), sua vantagem é que caso você tenha outras tags em meio aos Text Nodes, elas se preservarão.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p')

const text1 = document.createTextNode('text1 ')
const text2 = document.createTextNode('text2 ')
const text3 = document.createTextNode('text3')

p.appendChild(text1)
p.appendChild(text2)
p.appendChild(text3)

p.normalize()

console.log('ChildNodes:', p.childNodes.length)
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: @LukeNegreiros caso tenha duvidas sobre como aceitar a resposta, dê uma olhada aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta